# How to count number of files and subdirectories with shellscript?

Tags: file, shell, count

Current code:

```
echo "What absolute directory do you want to count?"
read DIR
cd $DIR
files=`ls`
file=0;
dir=0;
for d in $files
do
    dir=`expr $dir + 1`
done
for f in $files
do
    file=`expr $file + 1`
done
echo "Files $file"
echo "Directories $dir"
```

The proper output should be (based on the folder I measure):

```
Files: 20
Directories: 1
```

But I'm getting:

```
Files: 22
Directories: 22
```

So it's count files and subdirectories together, I want them to be separate. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest two changes: eliminate the unnecessary `files` variable, and use a glob instead of parsing the output of `ls`. Then use the `-d` test to see if each directory entry is a directory (if it's not, assume it's a regular file, unless you really care about distinguishing named pipes, character devices, block devices, etc) and use the `$((...))` expression for arithmetic.

```
echo "What absolute directory do you want to count?"
read DIR
cd "$DIR" || exit
file=0
dir=0
for d in *;
do
    if [ -d "$d" ]; then
        dir=$((dir+1))
    else
        file=$((file+1))
    fi
done
echo "Files $file"
echo "Directories $dir"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `find` like this:

```
Files="$(find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -printf x | wc -c)"
Directories="$(find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -printf x | wc -c)"
```

The `Directories` will also include the root directory `(.)`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done exactly in 3 lines:

```
read -p " Please enter the directory you want to count its files & subdirectories = " path

echo "Number of directories in $path =  "$(find $path/* -type d | wc -l)

echo "Number of Files in $path = "$(find $path/* -type f | wc -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding the OP is asking to count everything (files and folders) inside a given folder. If that's correct, then a one liner might do the work: `ls -l | wc -l`